# Hide multiple forms on one page and open them with specific links

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am creating a page and and it has multiple forms on each page. The forms are hidden but there is a link to each form. When the user clicks the link with the associated form than that form pops open in a lightbox, using colorbox.js. I have it working when only one form is on the page but I don't know how to create a script that works for multiple forms on one page. My script is:

```
   <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".myForm").hide();

        $(".link_to_form").click(function() {
            $(".myForm").show();
        });

        $(".link_to_form").colorbox({ 
            width: "50%", 
            inline: true,
            opacity: ".5", 
            href: ".myForm", 
            onClosed: function() {
                $(".myForm").hide();
            }

            });
    });
    </script>
```

The link that the user clicks on has a class of "link_to_form" and the actual form is in a div with the class of "myForm". Each form also has a specific id associated with it. So when a user clicks on the "register" form the form associated with that needs to pop up. Right now, if the user clicks on a link to any form all of the forms open in a lightbox.

Comment: How do you identify what form you want to show ?

Comment: That is what I am wondering as well :) I am needing to know how to do that jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you are binding a click event which calls show() on all .myForm matches found in the DOM. What you're really trying to do is bind an event to all .link_to_form matches in the DOM, and have the click event only open the one that is relevant to the click.

A good way to do this would be like this:

```
<div class="form_1">
   <a href="#" id="form_open_button">Open Form</a>
   <form class="my_form_class'>
   </form>
</div>

<div class="form_2">
   <a href="#" id="form_open_button">Open Form</a>
   <form class="my_form_class'>
   </form>
</div>

$('.form_open_button').click(
function() {
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

But you have to be sure to keep your forms IMMEDIATELY after the Anchor. If they aren't immediate, change next() to:

```
$(this).next('.my_form_class').toggle()
```

Comment: Be sure you understand the difference, though! When you call $('.myForm').show(), it will call the show() method on ALL .myForm classes found in the entire document. What you need to do is provide some context as to where you are searching, so that only the specific .myForm is the one that is affected. Placing it right after the link makes it easy to do this with .next(), but you can also do it by searching like $('.myForm', '.form_2') which will find it within the context of form_2 (better to do it with an ID than a class)

Comment: Ok, so I added $('.myForm').show(); right after $(this).next().toggle(); but it is still showing every form.

Comment: Noooo, you missed the point! You can't call $('.myForm') because it matches EVERY SINGLE .myForm in the Document! You need to somehow specify WHICH .myForm, so what you should do is call $(this).next('.myForm').show(); which will only affect the NEXT .myForm element.

Comment: Ok, yeah I understand now...I think. I did try your suggested line but it's still not working.

Comment: That definitely works and it works for me when I don't try to use colorbox but when using colorbox it fails.

Comment: Can you use JSFiddle (the site I linked before) and show me an example of your code / HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".link_to_form").click(function() {
    $(this).prev(".myForm").show();
});
```

Comment: Hmm I am still not seeing anything, as in the forms aren't showing up in the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a data- attribute to the link so it looks like

```
<a href='#' class="formLinks" data-form-id="form1" id="lnk_1">show</a>
<form id="form1"></form>
```

and then
your script would be

```
$('.formLinks').click(function(){
var formid =$(this).data('form-id');
$('#'+formid).show();
});
```